# Js script step to lunch kjbs if there satatus is ok in a monitoring table

Tags: database, pentaho

I need to know if I can create a JavaScript script that will step-by-step launch jobs (KJBs) one by one.
I plan to call the path of each KJB in a variable, and then pass it to the Java script step with a function lunching the kjb . The paths are stored in a table that schedules the launch of a script (if the status of the script is 'OK', then I can launch it). Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a javascript step for that. You can do it with the Job executor step in a transformation. Query the database table with status info, filter out anything that shouldn't run, then call the Job executor step for each row of incoming data, passing the input data rows as parameters. That job then calls the subjob using the parameters from the parent transformation.

Comment: thank you nsoua that help me a lot